# Restriction from subgroup of the Galois group of max. unr, ext. $G(\tilde{K}/\mathbb{Q}_{p})$ to $G(K/\mathbb{Q}_{p})$ is surjective?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

This is a question I'm struggling with for some time.

Let $K$ be a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ and let $\tilde{K}$ denote the maximal unramified extension of $K$.

We can then consider the continuous surjective restriction map of Galois groups
\begin{equation}
G(\tilde{K}/\mathbb{Q}_{p})\to G(K/\mathbb{Q}_{p}).
\end{equation}
I was told that we can actually restrict the domain of this map to the subgroup $(\varphi)$ of $G(\tilde{K}/\mathbb{Q}_{p})$ generated by the Frobenius element $\varphi$ of $K$ and this homomorphism still end up being surjective.

Now, why is that? I strongly feel that this has something to do with the fact that since $G(\tilde{K}/\mathbb{Q}_{p})$ is a procyclic group, since it has $(\varphi)$ as a dense cyclic subgroup , we could pick a pre-image of a given $\sigma\in G(K/\mathbb{Q}_{p})$ as something that could be "approximated" by elements in $G(\tilde{K}/\mathbb{Q}_{p})$, but this is just not precise. Is this some general property of procyclic groups? Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it. Does this not imply that $G(K/\Bbb{Q}_p)$ would always be cyclic. Why should that be the case? You are not assuming that $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is unramified, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen presumably the OP must be assuming that, since otherwise the restriction map would be undefined. On the other hand, this makes the answer considerably simpler.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Indeed, the question is much simpler if we assume that $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is unramified. But surely for all finite Galois extensions $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$  and all $\Bbb{Q}_p$-automorphisms $\sigma$ of $\tilde{K}$ we have $\sigma(K)=K$, so the restriction mapping $\sigma\mapsto \sigma\vert_K$ still makes sense?

Comment: But I think you are onto something! What is the Frobenius of, say, the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}_2$? For the Frobenius of $K$ to exist we need that $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ **is** unramified, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. And In order for restriction to be defined, don't we need $K\subset \tilde K$? We could first lift $\sigma$ to $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ and then restrict, but then there's no reason for the map to be surjective.

Comment: Well, $\tilde{K}$ was given to be the maximal unramified extension of $K$. But, sure, we need that for the restriction to make sense.

Comment: In general it looks like the image of $(\varphi)$ should be $G(K/K^\varphi)$, where $K^\varphi$ is the fixed field of $\varphi$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hey guys, thanks for the comments. I'm actually not supposing $K/\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is unramified. I didn't get why the restriction map wouldn't be well-defined if it was not unramified. What would be the problem? Also, I don't think I entirely follow the discussion. Don't we always have $K\subset\tilde{K}$?

Comment: I think the restriction map is well defined whenever $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is Galois. But IMVHO the claim is false unless $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is unramified. For example if $K$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}_2$, then
$G(K/\Bbb{Q}_2)\simeq S_3$. This is manifestly not a cyclic group so cannot be the image of $(\varphi)$ under the restriction homomorphism. Mind you, I also think that in this case $G(\tilde{K}/\Bbb{Q}_2)$ does not have a dense cyclic subgroup - for the same reason.

Comment: I'm a little confused. This question arrived in the context of local class field theory. More precisely, in the definition of the local reciprocity map. Isn't this the way we define it? Take a $\sigma\in G(K/\mathbb{Q}_{p})$, then take the "Frobenius lift" and then you go to the side of the norms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Frobenius is enough is just that your field is Henselian. Recall that finite, unramified extensions of local fields are determined completely by their residue fields. But then, this being a finite extension of finite fields, the residue field extension Galois group is generated by the Frobenius automorphism. Now when you pass to the profinite limit, the density of $\langle\varphi\rangle$ and the continuity gives you enough to work with just the Frobenius when you restrict.

So in short:  it has some to do with the group being pro-cyclic, but the real key here is that unramified extensions have Galois groups corresponding to the Galois groups of the residue field extension.

Comment: Wait a minute. I'm not supposing $K/\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is unramified, so are you speaking about $\tilde{K}/\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ when you say "finite, unramified, ..."? Then why would it be finite? I feel so lost in this one.

Comment: @Shoutre No I mean the extensions $L/K$ which are unramified. Remember that $\stackrel{\sim}{K}$ is a direct limit over **finite** unramified extensions of $K$. I suspected what you meant was for $\operatorname{Gal}(\stackrel{\sim}{K}/K)$ otherwise, the ramification of $K/\Bbb Q_p$ comes into play.

Comment: Ok, makes more sense now. About the sketch-argument about density and continuity: is it because the image of a dense subset under continuous map is dense? Looks right.

Comment: Not exactly, the point is that restriction is continuous, and every continuous map is determined completely on a dense subset.

Comment: @Shoutre and you see what I mean about $\operatorname{Gal}(\stackrel{\sim}{K}/K)$ vs over $\Bbb Q_p$, right? You get good Frobeniuses from unramified extensions of $K$, not starting all the way down at $\Bbb Q_p$ because there's ramification there.

Answer (score 2):

[This is supposed to be a comment, but I don't know how to type TEX in a comment]

The setting of the question is not clear at all. At the beginning, $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is a Galois, say of group $G$. By maximality of $\tilde {K}$ , the extension $\tilde {K} /\mathbf Q_p $ is Galois, and we have indeed a natural surjective  map $\pi$ from $G(\tilde {K} /\mathbf Q_p)$ onto $G $. But  its restriction to $(\phi)$ must have cyclic image, hence  can surely not be surjective if $G$ is not cyclic. And even if $G$ were cyclic, ramification could come into play in $ K /\mathbf Q_p$ . Suppose that $ K /\mathbf Q_p$ is ramified of degree $p$, hence totally ramified. Then the extension $\tilde {K} /\mathbf Q_p $ would split as the composite of $K$ and $\tilde {\mathbf Q_p}$, and $\pi$ would be an isomorphism of $G(\tilde {K} /K)$ onto $G(\tilde {\mathbf Q_p} /\mathbf Q_p)$. Finally, for the question to make sense, we need $ K /\mathbf Q_p$ to be unramified, but then $\tilde {K}= \tilde {\mathbf Q_p}$ and the answer becomes obvious.

Comment: You can just type $\TeX$ in a comment as you would in an answer.  I sometimes use the answer box to compose a comment, then cut and paste to a new comment.

Comment: @Eric Towers  Thank you for the teXnical hint !